# swiperjs sets wrong height for the first picture

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

Since I added autoheight for my swiperjs the div height for the first picture is false,
when I swipe and swipe back the picture gets the correct height. What can I add css or js wise to prevent this?
The Prefixed Height seems like the height of the direction arrows.

my js:

```
    var W = {
        init: !0,
        direction: "horizontal",
        touchEventsTarget: "wrapper",
        observer: 1,
        autoHeight: 1,
        observeParents: 1,
        initialSlide: 0,
        speed: 300,
        cssMode: !1,
        updateOnWindowResize: !0,
        resizeObserver: !0,
        nested: !1,
        createElements: !1,
        enabled: !0,
        focusableElements: "input, select, option, textarea, button, video, label",
        width: null,
        height: null,
        preventInteractionOnTransition: !1,
        userAgent: null,
        url: null,
        edgeSwipeDetection: !1,
        edgeSwipeThreshold: 20,
        setWrapperSize: !1,
        virtualTranslate: !1,
        effect: "slide",
        breakpoints: void 0,
        breakpointsBase: "window",
        spaceBetween: 0,
        slidesPerView: 1,
        slidesPerGroup: 1,
        slidesPerGroupSkip: 0,
        slidesPerGroupAuto: !1,
        centeredSlides: !1,
        centeredSlidesBounds: !1,
        slidesOffsetBefore: 0,
        slidesOffsetAfter: 0,
        normalizeSlideIndex: !0,
        centerInsufficientSlides: !1,
        watchOverflow: !0,
        roundLengths: !1,
        touchRatio: 1,
        touchAngle: 45,
        simulateTouch: !0,
        shortSwipes: !0,
        longSwipes: !0,
        longSwipesRatio: 0.5,
        longSwipesMs: 300,
        followFinger: !0,
        allowTouchMove: !0,
        threshold: 0,
        touchMoveStopPropagation: !1,
        touchStartPreventDefault: !0,
        touchStartForcePreventDefault: !1,
        touchReleaseOnEdges: !1,
        uniqueNavElements: !0,
        resistance: !0,
        resistanceRatio: 0.85,
        watchSlidesProgress: !1,
        grabCursor: !1,
        preventClicks: !0,
        preventClicksPropagation: !0,
        slideToClickedSlide: !1,
        preloadImages: 1,
        updateOnImagesReady: 1,
        loop: !1,
        loopAdditionalSlides: 0,
        loopedSlides: null,
        loopFillGroupWithBlank: !1,
        loopPreventsSlide: !0,
        rewind: !1,
        allowSlidePrev: !0,
        allowSlideNext: !0,
        swipeHandler: null,
        noSwiping: !0,
        noSwipingClass: "swiper-no-swiping",
        noSwipingSelector: null,
        passiveListeners: !0,
        maxBackfaceHiddenSlides: 10,
        containerModifierClass: "swiper-",
        slideClass: "swiper-slide",
        slideBlankClass: "swiper-slide-invisible-blank",
        slideActiveClass: "swiper-slide-active",
        slideDuplicateActiveClass: "swiper-slide-duplicate-active",
        slideVisibleClass: "swiper-slide-visible",
        slideDuplicateClass: "swiper-slide-duplicate",
        slideNextClass: "swiper-slide-next",
        slideDuplicateNextClass: "swiper-slide-duplicate-next",
        slidePrevClass: "swiper-slide-prev",
        slideDuplicatePrevClass: "swiper-slide-duplicate-prev",
        wrapperClass: "swiper-wrapper",
        runCallbacksOnInit: !0,
        _emitClasses: !1,
    };
```

I already tried adding the following:
`preloadImages:1`,
`updateOnImagesReady:1`,
`observer:1` and
`observeParents:1`.
removing lazy loading